# unable to open primary document entity

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new at Ubuntu please anyone can help me to figure out this problem?
Whenever i run this command

```
7z x -so SwissProt.xml.7z | xqilla -i /dev/stdin q.xq
```

It displays error "unable to open primary document entity" like this one.

Comment: That error sounds like an XML parser chewing on bad XML.  Have you tried testing the XML file with `xmllint`?

Comment: sorry,no i don't know how to try xmllint

Comment: Well, start by just extracting the 7zip archive, so you have the XML file.  Then just run `xmllint SwissProt.xml`.  See the manual page (`man xmllint`) for details.

Comment: after extracting the zip file when i run xmllint SwissProt.xml command then killed message is displayed :/ in the shell